# Valgrind said, that "carry" is not initialized, but it is

Tags: c++, valgrind

I am writing a `big_integer` class for C++; valgrind found an error that I don't know how to fix.  The class works correctly, so I'm not even sure whether I need to fix it.

Here is a part of the code:

```
big_integer& big_integer::operator+=(big_integer const& rhs){
    size_t i = 0;
    __uint128_t carry = 0;
    while (std::max(length, rhs.length) > i){
        __uint128_t sum = (__uint128_t)arr[i] + (__uint128_t)rhs[i] + carry; // line 197
        if (SIZE_MAX <= sum - 1){ //line 198
            carry = 1;
        } else
            carry = 0;
        arr[i] = (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max() & sum);
        i++;
    }
    length = std::max(length, rhs.length);
    if (carry != 0){
        arr[i]= 1;
        length++;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Valgrid says:

```
==31141== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31141==    at 0x406A37: big_integer::operator+=(big_integer const&) (big_integer.cpp:198)
==31141==    by 0x404884: main (main.cpp:21)
==31141==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31141==    at 0x4069E4: big_integer::operator+=(big_integer const&) (big_integer.cpp:197)
==31141== 
==31141== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31141==    at 0x406A3C: big_integer::operator+=(big_integer const&) (big_integer.cpp:198)
==31141==    by 0x404884: main (main.cpp:21)
==31141==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31141==    at 0x4069E4: big_integer::operator+=(big_integer const&) (big_integer.cpp:197)
==31141== 
==31141== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31141==    at 0x406A41: big_integer::operator+=(big_integer const&) (big_integer.cpp:198)
==31141==    by 0x404884: main (main.cpp:21)
==31141==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31141==    at 0x4069E4: big_integer::operator+=(big_integer const&) (big_integer.cpp:197)
==31141== 
==31141== 
==31141== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31141==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31141==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==31141== 
==31141== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31141== 
==31141== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31141== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It says that carry is not initialized, but I'm sure that it is!

If I delete `if` from within the `while` loop, valgrind no longer complains.

What should I do?

Comment: Why do think the problem is `carry`? Could the problem be in `__uint128_t sum = (__uint128_t)arr[i] + (__uint128_t)rhs[i] + carry;` How is `arr`defined? How is `[]`defined for big_integer?

Comment: looks to me like the uninitialized part is the `i` not `carry`...

Comment: Fix your indentation.

Comment: I suspect the actual problem is the variable (member?) named `i`, `length`, or the arrays/pointers `arr` or `rhs`.   It is possiby a sign of a constructor not properly implemented  (or not implemented at all, so the compiler provides one e.g. a copy constructor that does not do what is needed)

Comment: The use of `std::max(length, rhs.length)` implies i can be greater than `rhs.length-1`.  We don't seem to know what `rhs.length` actually means, but it seems likely `rhs[i]` is uninitialized when `i>=rhs.length`.  Uninitialized memory is often semi-reliably equal to zero and this code looks like it depends on uninitialized parts of rhs[] being zero.  So Valgrind is correctly warning that what seems to work will not be really reliable.

Comment: The output (lines 197 and 199) doesn't seem to match your code (lines 197 and 198, according to your comments).

Comment: There can be multiple issues in the code above, we can't say as crucial bit of code is not copied here. U need to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Look into http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @StillLearning
cose if I comment "if", where carry became 1 or 0, the problem goes out.

Comment: @mark its typo, I had defined

Comment: @JSF
arr is vector with property, when i > length, it returns 0. But, anyway, vagrind warning exists when I do big_integer a(2) and a += 2 in main.
It means, that big_integer uses only one cell of vector, and i always equal 1.
I have compiled with -O0, but nothing new happend.

Comment: @Anonym - there is no way `carry` can be uninitialized - it is impossible as it is initialized by this line: `__uint128_t carry = 0;` So when you comment out the `if`and the problem goes way, it tells you that you have a problem with `if (SIZE_MAX <= sum - 1)` and that is actually also what you are told: `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value`

Comment: @Anonym - I'm pretty sure that line 197 is `while (std::max(length, rhs.length) > i){` and line 199 is `if (SIZE_MAX <= sum - 1)`. So how is the variable `i`initialized/controlled? I assume it is a member variable, rigth?

Comment: @StillLearning
I delete some code, that don't make influence, and the first line in function is `__uint128_t i = 0; `
the difference between lines was caused by editing code, valgrind in fact points at these lines, that I comented (at 197 and 198). The line 199 = 198 where i used valgrind

Comment: @Anonym - If the real code isn't like the code in your question then update the code in the question including line numbers. There is an `edit`link for that. We can't help you if you show the wrong code...

Comment: @StillLearing
already has done

Comment: @Anonym: So if you return from the array when `i < length` and you return zero when `i > length`, it sounds like you have a bug when `i == length`. Even if not, double-check your indexing code anyways: it is implicated in this bug, so you can't afford to ignore it. Have you considered the case when `length < rhs.length` though? `arr[i]` sounds like a different code path than `rhs[i]`.

Comment: @Anonym - The update helps - now the problem report changed. On line 197: `__uint128_t sum = (__uint128_t)arr[i] + (__uint128_t)rhs[i] + carry;` something is uninitialized. So there is something wrong with either `arr[i]` or `rhs[i]` Could it be that `rhs[i]` should be `rhs.arr[i]` ?

Comment: @Anonym - or could it be that your `xxx[i]` doesn't return 0 when `i >= length` as you told in a previous comment?

Comment: @StillLearning
The fact that program is working correctly on all tests, and I am trying to fix only valgrind warrings. It couldn't, I test another time, in test 1 += 2, `arr[i] = 1;` `rhs[i] = 2;` and `sum = 3;`

Comment: Uh you edit the code to add another line.. that strongly suggests this isn't your real code otherwise why would you have deleted that one line before posting? Please post the *exact code* that shows the problem and make sure it is a complete program.

Comment: @Anonmy - So you have tested a few cases (let's say 100 cases) and seen them working. So your conclusion is that valgrind is wrong. Hmm... Sorry - I don't want to be rude but 35 years of programming experience tells me that you are most likely wrong. It is very seldom that tools used my many thousands has a bug. Inexperienced programmers does however have a lot. I tried to help you but as long as you resist to post the relevant code that we ask for it is impossible. My last suggestion is to check whether valgrind support the type `__uint128_t` - it is not part of the standard so maybe it isn't

Comment: @Anonym - you could avoid the __uint128_t and instead check for overflow before adding things together. Such code would perform better and also be based on standard size integers only. Good luck in finding the root cause.